# Pointers not actually pointing to objects themselves?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I currently have a vector of a class `Foo` and another vector of pointers that point to a subset of the `Foo`'s in the vector. I currently have a function that selects some pointers from the `vector<Foo *>` and deletes them from the `vector<Foo>` that actually contains them. Thus, at the outset, the two vectors look like this:

```
//Foo classes in vector<Foo>
a
b
c
d
```

and

```
//Foo pointers in vector<Foo *>
*a
*b
*c
*d
```

However, I discover that after deleting a `Foo`, say `b`, they look like this:

```
//Foo classes in vector<Foo>
a
c
d
```

and

```
//Foo pointers in vector<Foo *>
*a
*c
*d
*d
```

How come the pointer to `c` in `vector<Foo *>` doesn't stay pointed to `c` after `b` gets deleted in `vector<Foo>`? Is there any way to remedy this?

(I understand that if I delete `b`, the original pointer to `b` would be a dangling one; however, since I did not intend to access `b` after its deletion anyway, I thought it wouldn't matter and I could go to the next index with the pointer to `c`)

**EDIT:**

As requested, the code where the pointer vector is filled:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) //a is the vector<Foo>
{
    Foo * thisFoo = &a[i];
    if(someConditionMet)
        b.push_back(thisFoo); //b is the vector<Foo *>
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you fill the array, at thats the essential part.

Comment: Let me put on my psychic hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `vector` stores its elements in an array.  An array is a contiguous sequence of elements.

If you have a `vector` containing elements `a, b, c, d` and remove element `b`, then elements `c` and `d` are moved down one index in the array to fill the hole created by the removed element, leaving an array containing `a, c, d`.

The pointers don't "follow" the elements in the `vector` as they are moved.  If you have a pointer "to `c`," that pointer really points to "the element at index `2` in the array."  When you remove `b` from the array, "the element at index `2`" is then `d`, not `c`.

If you want an object to have a fixed address that never changes, you should dynamically allocate it yourself and track it using a smart pointer (like `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`).

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that the pointers just point to the memory location instead of following the actual object itself.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Well, my psychic powers aren't particularly reliable.  I like the opportunity to try using them, though.  :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that removing an element from a `std::vector` can cause it to be reallocated, invalidating all pointers to elements thereof.

Comment: @Novelocrat:  An erasure can never cause a reallocation.

Comment: Alternatively, @wrongusername could switch to a `std::list`. Erasing elements from a list does not move the following elements.

Comment: @James McNellis: You're right. I had thought that erasing elements allowed reallocation to reduce memory footprint, but it appears not to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accomplish something like this, you aren't going to be able to use `vector<foo>` to actually be in charge of the `foo` objects themselves. It looks to me like your sub-vector of `foo*`'s must be actually pointing to the memory that the `vector<foo>` is in charge of. (Thus, that's why you still see the additional pointer at the end that points to `d`, and you still have a length of 4.)

Seems to me, what you really want to do is use two `vector<foo*>`'s, and manually create the objects that are being stored in the first rather than having the vector itself in charge of the objects. Then have your second `vector<foo*>` simply copy the pointers to the objects you've created. That way when you delete an item from the first `vector<foo*>`, it will only remove its copy of the pointer, and your second `vector<foo*>` will be unaffected.

Think of it without the vector involved:

```
// create the initial storage for all the foo
foo* fooarray = new foo[foo_count];

// create all the foos for the array
for (int i=0; i < foo_count; ++i)
   fooarray = new foo();

// get a pointer to a subset of foo 
foo* foo_subset_pointer = &fooarray[10];

// make a list of a subset of the fooarray pointers
foo* foo_subset_list = new foo[10];
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
    foo_subset_list = fooarray[i];
```

so, now when you remove an element from fooarray:

```
// remove fooarray[3]
delete fooarray[3]; 
for (int i=4; i < 20; ++i)
   fooarray[i-1] = fooarray[i];
```

`foo_subset_pointer` will have have its original item 3 removed, since it was just a pointer to the existing array. (And if you access `foo_subset_pointer[19]`, it will still have a pointer to the same thing as `foo_subset_pointer[18]`, because the items weren't zeroed...)

But worse, `foo_subset_list[3]` still points to the original location: but it's invalid because it was deleted! This is why you don't want to have the vector being in charge of your list items when you're dealing with a subset that you want to keep around.

Instead, it sounds like you want your first vector to only do the removal of the item (the `for` loop above) but not the `delete`.  In this case, it leaves your `foo_subset_list[3]` untouched and still pointing to a valid `foo`. The additional difficulty is that you now have to be sure to do the `delete foo_subset_list[3];` at some point in the future. But it allows you to have the behavior that seems to be what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

When an object in a `vector` is removed, all the objects at larger indices in the `vector` are moved down to close up the "hole". Pointers to any of those objects become invalid. The only way to detect the situation is not to get into that situation in the first place -- don't store pointers to objects in non-`const` `vector`s, because it's dangerous.